# How to use anguluar i18n in html template with variables?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

Is it possible to use variables in an angular template i18n string?

In TypeScript I can use template string, eg:

```js
public welcomeMessage = $localize`:@@test.welcome: Hello ${this.name}:user_name:! How's your day?`;
```

Can I use something similar in html templates? eg

```html
<p i18n="@@test.welcome">Hello {{name}}:user_name:! How's your day?</p>
```

Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've ran into the same issue and the Angular i18n documentation is somewhat unclear about interpolation and naming the interpolated placeholder. For simple text interpolation you can just use:

```html
<p i18n>Hello {{name}}! How's your day?</p>
```

But AFAIK there is currently no way of naming the interpolated placeholder, it will just end up being the interpolated text:

```xml
<source>Hello <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{name}}"/>! How&apos;s your day?</source>
```

However, you could always change the placeholder (`equiv-text`) manually in the extracted XLIFF file.